# Inherit as required only some fields from parent pandera SchemaModel

Tags: python, pydantic, pandera

I have Input and Output pandera SchemaModels and the Output inherits the Input which accurately represents that all attributes of the Input schema are in the scope of the Output schema.

What I want to avoid is inheriting all attributes as required (non-Optional) as they are rightly coming from the Input schema. Instead I want to preserve them as required for the Input schema but define which of them remain required for the Output schema while the other inherited attributes become optional.

This pydantic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948723/how-to-extend-a-pydantic-object-and-change-some-fields-type) is similar and has solution for defining `__init_subclass__` method in the parent class. However, this doesn't work out of the box for pandera classes and I'm not sure if it is even implementable or the right approach.

```
import pandera as pa
from typing import Optional
from pandera.typing import Index, DataFrame, Series, Category

class InputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):

    reporting_date: Series[pa.DateTime] = pa.Field(coerce=True)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, optional_fields=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if optional_fields:
            for field in optional_fields:
                cls.__fields__[field].outer_type_ = Optional
                cls.__fields__[field].required = False    


class OutputSchema(InputSchema, optional_fields=['reporting_date']):

    test: Series[str] = pa.Field()


@pa.check_types
def func(inputs: DataFrame[InputSchema]) -> DataFrame[OutputSchema]:
    inputs = inputs.drop(columns=['reporting_date'])
    inputs['test'] = 'a'
    return inputs

data = pd.DataFrame({'reporting_date': ['2023-01-11', '2023-01-12']})

func(data)
```

Error:

```
---> 18 class OutputSchema(InputSchema, optional_fields=['reporting_date']):
KeyError: 'reporting_date'
```

Edit:

Desired outcome to be able to set which fields from the inherited schema remain required while the remaining become optional:

```
class InputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):

    reporting_date: Series[pa.DateTime] = pa.Field(coerce=True)
    other_field: Series[str] = pa.Field()


class OutputSchema(InputSchema, required=['reporting_date'])

    test: Series[str] = pa.Field()
```

The resulting `OutputSchema` has `reporting_date` and `test` as required while `other_field` as optional.

Comment: Can you add the schema to our `InputSchema`? And what is the desired output for `OutputSchema`? (Give an example please.) Will help us answer your Q.

I personally think `__init_subclass__` is too complex for what you are trying to solve. There is probs a simpler solution. Add details and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: @YaakovBressler I've added desired output but I don't understand your question to add schema to InputSchema, it is already there and inherited from pa.SchemaModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution by reusing existing type annotation from the input schema:

```
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional
from pandera.typing import Index, DataFrame, Series, Category
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel
from typing import Annotated, Type


def copy_field(from_model: Type[BaseModel], fname: str, annotations: dict[str, ...]):
    annotations[fname] = from_model.__annotations__[fname]


class InputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    reporting_date: Series[pa.DateTime] = pa.Field(coerce=True)
    not_inherit: Series[str]

class OutputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    test: Series[str] = pa.Field()
    copy_field(InputSchema, "reporting_date", __annotations__)
    # reporting_date: Series[pa.DateTime] = pa.Field(coerce=True)
    # not_inherit: Optional[Series[str]]


data = pd.DataFrame({
    'reporting_date': ['2023-01-11', '2023-01-12'],
    'not_inherit': ['a','a']
})

@pa.check_types
def func(
    inputs: DataFrame[InputSchema]
) -> DataFrame[OutputSchema]:
    inputs = inputs.drop(columns=['not_inherit'])
    inputs['test'] = 'a'
    return inputs

func(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [on pandera's issue tracker](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/discussions/990), with [a docs update](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/pull/1012/files) on track for the next pandera release. There is no clean solution, but the most simple one is to exclude columns by overloading `to_schema`:

```py
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series

class InputSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    reporting_date: Series[pa.DateTime] = pa.Field(coerce=True)

class OutputSchema(InputSchema):
    test: Series[str]
    
    @classmethod
    def to_schema(cls) -> pa.DataFrameSchema:
        return super().to_schema().remove_columns(["reporting_date"])
```

This runs without `SchemaError` against your check function.